# cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference

Tags: java

Hi I'm creating a simple login system. I have 2 users of my application

1. user
2. admin

I'm trying that if the user login app intends to user activity and if the admin login app intents to admin activity.
For this, I am passing a String "admin" when the new admin register and "user" went the new user register, And in Login Activity, I match these String but this error occurs.

```
       mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(dbemail, dbpassword)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        FirebaseUser users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        if (users != null){

                             DatabaseReference databaseReference = (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
                                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                            if (snapshot.child("as").equals("Admin")){
                                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                        }
                                    });
                        }

                        else {

                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failed to login! Please check your credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "This account don't exist! Create Account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

`addValueEventListener` [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) returns `ValueEventListener` type, not `DatabaseReference` so it cannot be cast.
If you don't need `DatabaseReference` object, it should be enough:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
                                    .addValueEventListener(...);
```